# IntelliJ: how do you override VM options for a single test?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I want to run a single test method in a test class. Running "Modify Configuration" (screenshot below), there is no option to override a system property. It is possible to override environment variables (`System.getenv`) but that is not the same.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VM options are in the third field where you currently see `-ea`. You can add your own VM options there.